# Как сделать paging страницы google travel без использования selenium подобных модулей?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу на языке: python
Модули: BeutifulSoup4, requests, lxml

Есть ли способ получить адреса следующих страниц с помощью get запроса, без роботов и вебдрайверов?

Пример страницы: [https://www.google.com/travel/search?q=Москва](https://www.google.com/travel/search?q=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Спасибо за внимание.